# Which transformation should I use to reduce a map to the item with smallest value for each row?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Using pyspark, what is the best way to reduce a map to the item with smallest value for each row?

In the below example, I would like to only take the action that is occurred first:

Example dataframe:

```
+------+-----------------------+
| Name | Actions               |
+------+-----------------------+
|Alice |{1978:'aaa',1981:'bbb'}|
|Jack  |{1999:'xxx',1988:'yyy'}|
|Bill  |{1992:'zzz'}           |
+------+-----------------------+
```

Desired DF:

```
+------+----------------------+
| Name | Actions              |
+------+----------------------+
|Alice |{1978:'aaa'}          |
|Jack  |{1988:'yyy'}          |
|Bill  |{1992:'zzz'}          |
+------+----------------------+
```

Comment: One option would be to first Explode the rows into multiple rows per "Actions" column. Then using Window functions and doing a dense_rank on the dates. But I suspect there can be a better way in terms of performance.

Comment: What's the schema of your dataframe? [Edit] your question with the output of `df.printSchema()`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to arrays with [`map_keys`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#map_keys) and [`map_values`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#map_values):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([("Name", {1978: 'aaa', 1981: 'bbb'})], ("Name", "Actions"))

df_array = df.select(
    "Name", 
    map_keys("Actions").alias("keys"), 
    map_values("Actions").alias("values")
)
```

Combine both with [`arrays_zip`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#arrays_zip), sort with [`array_sort`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_sort):

```
df_array_sorted = df_array.withColumn("sorted", arrays_zip("keys", "values"))
```

take the first element and convert back to map with [`map_from_entries`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#map_from_entries)

```
df_array_sorted.select("Name", map_from_entries(array(col("sorted")[0])).alias("Actions")).show()
# +----+-------------+
# |Name|      Actions|
# +----+-------------+
# |Name|[1981 -> bbb]|
# +----+-------------+
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean creating a dataframe for each row of the original dataset, sort, select and do it for all rows? I am not sure about the performance of this.